# Making a GridView column contain only dates and no times and still correctly sort

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm filling a `GridView` from a `DataTable`. I would like to have just the date part of the datetime fields to show.

I have used :

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MyDatetime,103) AS 'DateOnly'
```

This displays fine but sorts 'incorrectly' (it is treated as a string rather then a date)
The simple solution I want to avoid would be

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MyDatetime,102) AS 'DateOnly'
```

i.e. have the year first, this would sort correctly but isn't quite right.

I've also tried:

```
CONVERT(date,MyDatetime,103) AS 'DateOnly' and 
DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, MyDatetime)) AS 'DateOnly'
```

These look fine in sql server, but when rendered in the `GridView` add on the time 00:00:00 after the date. - on the plus side the sort works fine.

The columns in the `DataTable` can vary so the columns are generated at run time and I can not use any solutions that involve editing the field like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="DataFieldName" DataFormatString="{0:d}"></asp:BoundField>
```

I feel like I'm almost there but I just cant find the last piece to the puzzle.

Comment: If anyone can tell me how to make my code blocks show correctly that would be great, I add 4 spaces before but doesn't seam to help

Comment: Hi, See this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104912/sort-on-date-column-gridview .... It may help you...

Comment: The catch is, the _concept_ behind that last solution is the correct one; formatting is a _locale-dependent_, display-time concern.  You should be dealing with an actual 'date' object up until it's formatted for display.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse are you saying I just need to make a change to the locale? Do you know what needs to be changed?

Comment: I've never worked with ASP, so I have no clue what your actual problem is.  What I was getting at is that your DB server shouldn't be the part doing the formatting; that's the display's job.  The server should only be concerned with the 'value' of the data (which may not be internally represented as you may expect...)

Comment: I agree, I just need to know how to handle the formatting. Actually thought it would be a common issue with a simple/common solution.

Comment: I finally did it on RowDataBound like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249629/formatting-dynamic-gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it on RowDataBound like this: stackoverflow.com/questions/4249629/formatting-dynamic-gridview

I'm sure there must be a better solution but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you `convert to varchar and order`, then you are actually not `ordering by` date but by a `varchar string`.

To get rid of time from datetime, Convert datetime to date and your sorting should be okay (as you said)

```
CONVERT(date, MyDatetime) AS 'DateOnly'
```

To format the date (as dd-MM-yyyy) on gridview, use format string as below. Note, in this case your data-bound field should be a date type

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="DataFieldName" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}">
</asp:BoundField>
```

***Or*** you can use `sql-server` to format date using `CONVERT` to a specific format as here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

For example, you could convert to 103 style and *order by* your original `MyDatetime` as below

```
Select col1,col2, convert(varchar,myDateTime,103) as 'DateOnly'
From yourTable
Order by myDateTime
```

Comment: I'm not sure if my question wasn't clear but the boundField will not work as I am auto-generating the columns. Unfortunately due to how the sorting works I can't display one thing and sort by another

Comment: Then you can use `CONVERT(Varchar,CONVERT(Date, myDateTime),120)` (ie; first get rid of time and then convert to `yyyy-mm-dd` format). **As long as you get your year(first)mm(second)dd(third), ordering should be fine**. There are few more such options here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) (ex; 102, 111, 112, 120,..). Otherwise you have to stop auto generating columns and manually define them.